# How to temporarily escape anaconda/conda shell environment

Tags: anaconda, conda

Once you've installed anaconda/conda, and configured your shell init file to set the path, how can you temporarily escape from that environment to use the system tools, for example the version of python that was installed natively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did a default install and, therefore, followed [the best practice configuration introduced in Conda v.4.4](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell), then it is simply a matter of deactivating the **base** env:

```
conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

merv's answer is better...

Here is a way to do this on the fly without editing one's init files:

```
(base) ➜  ~ which python
/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) ➜  ~ echo $PATH
/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin:/home/xxx/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(base) ➜  ~ export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '/conda/ {next} {print}' | sed 's/:*$//')
(base) ➜  ~ echo $PATH                                                                
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(base) ➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
(base) ➜  ~
```